# Not Getting Tabbar after navigate to another ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

[image]

**

> Above screen navigate to below screen and not getting Tabbar.

**
[image]

Comment: Is the second VC presented modally?

Comment: check your second viewcontroller's settings. check that `hide bottom bar when push` is not enable ! ans show your code for showing new view controller!

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated) 
    self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = false;
}
```

Comment: @Paras did you try this?